# Trouble debugging - VSCode - configuring JSON - Program path is missing or invalid

Tags: c++, json, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am having trouble getting the F5 debugger to work properly.

I have been trying to follow the Microsoft tutorial to get things going, but after building successfully the debugging process never really works out the way it should.

When I use the Ctrl + Shift + B command to build, it successfully creates a `main.exe` file, but I cannot change the `launch.json` file in a way that works hand-in-hand.

While `tasks.json` has this
`"-o","${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` as the object path/name, 'main.cpp' is compiled into `main.exe`.

So, initially, I had tried to set `launch.json` to have `program": ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe`.  Which would be neat and effective, matching the build file that would be produced.

I get this error:
[image: screenshot]

Next, I tried to change `launch.json` to run as `a.exe` hardcoded. In the PS terminal within VSCode, I ran `g++ .\main.cpp` and produced an `a.exe` file.  Which successfully allows F5 debugging giving me an exit code '0' in the debug console when I changed `launch.json` to have `"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\a.exe"`.

I have also tried to use `${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe` with no luck.

It makes no logical sense to me that the same parameters for `cwd` with the same object name in tasks won't run successfully for debugging in launch.

The entire tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

The entire launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\a.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Could someone please take a look for me?  This is infuriating..  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title, nor edit the solution into your question. Instead, post the solution as an "answer" below, and press the checkmark next to it to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. Hopefully will help someone else, too.

First I updated the architecture portion of the options for `launch.json` - not relevant to the file-path issue, but figured I would mention.  Add `"targetArchitecture": "x64"`(or the 32bit option if necessary) to the `tasks.json` file.

==================================================================

Solution: After fiddling around a bit I have found that `tasks.json` was the issue, not `launch.json`. After a good amount of confusion I took a break and came back to the problem and noticed that tasks was running `cpp.exe` to build the file. Out of curiosity I replaced it with g++.exe and voilà - it works.

So, if you have issues with using F5 in VSCode with MinGW for compiling/debugging - ensure that g++.exe is compiling. At least from my limited knowledge, that should fix the issue if you are running VSCode and using MinGW for building/debugging.